# Have find_by in rails return multiple results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to return all groups created by a user. All of the groups are associated with the user id. When I run a find_by query it only returns the first result. Is there a way for it to return multiple?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change find_by to find_all_by and it will return all matching results.

Comment: Wow that had a simple answer.

Comment: Note: Deprecated in Ruby 4.2, use `where` instead. See AarCee's answer below.

Answer (score 32):

I'm writing a separate answer because I can't comment on James Lowrey's answer as I don't have 50 points.

find_all_by is deprecated (Ruby 4.2).

To get a list of active records from models, do:

```
Model.where(attribute_name: val)
```

For example, to find all records in Vehicle table (having column name "model_name") such that the value of model_name is "Audi", do

```
@vehicles = Vehicle.where(model_name: "Audi")
```

You can iterate through these like so:

```
<%  @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think find_all_by may be deprecated now (at least, I couldn't get it to work). I believe the 'where' function is now recommended

```
where("name LIKE ?","%#{search}%")
where(instructor_id: params[:choosen_instructor_id])   
where ("id = ?",id_val)
```

In case you didn't know, the ? and parameter list is to prevent SQL injections

Answer (score 0):

User class has id as primary key.
which is stored as user_id in Group class
 
Then to find all groups associated with that user could be found as.
@groups=Group.find_all_by_user_id(user_id)